# PHP - pop up using Twig translation

Tags: php, templates, twig, translation

I am using Twig in a custom built framework.
To use pop ups, I am dynamically inserting html in a div on a page and then show the div. The content however needs to be translated. Twig won't work here (as far as I know). What could be a solution preventing to create a php translation file as I don't want to use two separate translation mechanisms.

Comment: "*Twig won't work here (as far as I know)*" - How are you "translating" your non pop-up content then?

Comment: with Twig, but Twig translates it on the fly when loading an HTML page. As far as I know I won't be able to translate text in a dynamically generated (with PHP) pop up.

Comment: How are you inserting the dynamic HTML? I'd guess you could use `twig`as well to render the HTML (and translate it) and send it back

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you are generating the HTML directly from the javascript side? If so, you can transfer ready translations to javascript (via API or together with an HTML document) and then insert them into your generated HTML.

I don't recommend it, but you can also send an API request, which will return you ready HTML - with appropriate translations inserted.

Comment: As OP stated in the question: The HTML is being generated with PHP and twig

Comment: Indeed: the HTML for the pop-up is generated by PHP. So Twig is not able to parse it a this stage. The HTML is inserted into a div on a HTML page and shown using javascript.